# Sqlite delete rows older than

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have records in database:

```
record B with property `Checked` set to be current date in UTC.
record A with property `Checked` set to be current date in UTC - 48 hours.
```

Then I want to create query to delete rows with property `Checked` older than 24 hours.

In my case only `A` should be deleted. `Checked` is stored as `bigint` in database.

```
db.Execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE Checked <= strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-1 day'))"); // A and B are not deleted
db.Execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE Checked <= datetime('now', '-1 day')"); // A and B are deleted
db.Execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE Date(checked) <= datetime('now', '-1 day')"); // A and B are not deleted
db.Execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE datetime(checked) <= datetime('now', '-1 day')"); // A and B are not deleted
```

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong there?

Comment: Your `Checked` column stores bigint values as Unix epoch time? Then you should use `datetime(Checked, 'unixepoch')`

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html very carefully and thoroughly.  Look at what those `datetime()` expressions return, and look at what's in the column you're trying to compare that too. Re-read the section on comparisons in the datatype page if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

```
datetime(Checked/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch') <= datetime('now', '-1 day')
```